# objective C Iterate Method Call

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, methods, call

How can I iterate a method call for example.

```
[self revertBox1];
[self revertBox2];
[self revertBox3];
[self revertBox4];
[self revertBox5];

// They are as many as 20.

example1 * xmp = [[example1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"example1" bundle:nil];

// How can I iterate the class instantiation example1, example2, example3

// If I use this method.. 

NSString *classNameStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"example%d", i];
Class cls = NSClassFromString(classNameStr);
cls *obj = [[[cls alloc] initWithNibName:classNameStr bundle:nil];

//I receive an error [ Use of undeclared identifier 'obj' ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to iterate the method calls,

```
for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {

    NSString *selectorNameStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"revertBox%d", i];
    SEL sel = NSSelectorFromString(selectorNameStr);
    [self performSelector:sel];
}
```

If you want to iterate the Class name, you can do like this,

```
for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {

    NSString *classNameStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"example%d", i];
    Class cls = NSClassFromString(classNameStr);
    cls *obj = [[[cls alloc] initWithNibName:classNameStr bundle:nil];
}
```

Comment: Clever, but user797819 really just needs to re-factor his original code and declarations a bit.

Comment: ---- NSString *classNameStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"example%d", i];


---- Class cls = NSClassFromString(classNameStr);


---- cls *obj = [[[cls alloc] initWithNibName:classNameStr bundle:nil];



    //Use of undeclared identifier 'obj'

Answer (score 4):

You should rethink your design and approach to this...Instead of having 20 methods names -revertBoxN, how about make one method:

```
- (void)revertBox:(int)index { }
```

You would then have to replace your list of ivars (exampleN) with a C-array of a certain size.

You can use a terse loop to iterate through elements and avoid repetitive code.

Hopefully you can follow what I'm saying...I don't think I should have to go into more detail (otherwise you should learn the basics of Objective-C (that includes C!).